# SQL Database with Free Trial

Tags: azure

I just signed up for a free trial, and got £enough free credit to cover the fees for a month use of SQL DB

I'd like to trial a SQL database. It let's me go through the motions, but when it tries to create the database it fails with a response "The operation is not supported for your subscription offer type"

However, on the Azure free trial page* it clearly says 'SQL Databases'

What do I need to do to create a SQL Database with the free trial?

- I removed a link here, to remove any doubt that I'm advertising the said service. You'll be able to find a link if you're remotely interested.

Comment: Did you just sign up as in a few minutes ago? If so, wait a couple more and try again. I've seen it take a bit for new services to be provisioned.

Comment: @OlaEkdahl well it was about 45 minutes or so ago. V. frustrating.